# jQuery UI dialog closes on enter

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, enter

When I open a jQuery UI Dialog widget and the content in the dialog contains a textbox the dialog automatically closes when I press enter. This seems to happen only when using IE9 or IE10. I do not want the dialog the close when I press enter in the textbox.

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Testpage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myDialog').dialog();
    });
</script>

</head> 

<body>  

    <div id="myDialog">
        Some text           
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When you open this HTML page the dialog will close when you press enter (only in IE9+). Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/3FVsp/) jsfiddle seems to work fine...even in IE 10 and 9

Comment: When I use your jsFiddle pressing enter in the textbox opens another page as if there's some sort of form submit. This behavior does not show in Chrome and Firefox. I want the dialog to nothing when I press enter in the textbox.

Comment: The fiddle isn't using the same version of jQuery UI as seen above.

Comment: the issue is generated but IE, not by jQuery UI, and applies to "button" element without a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in jQuery UI 1.10.x the close button in the upper-right changed from an `<a>` to a `<button>`. Since this button doesn't specify a `type` attribute, it is considered to be `type="submit"`. When you press enter in IE9+, the browser looks for a submit button, finds the close button, and presses it.

There are a couple of ways to work around this problem, I'd argue that the best way is to correct the type of the close button by overriding the `_init` function of ui.dialog:

```
var baseInit = $.ui.dialog.prototype._init;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._init = function () {
    baseInit.apply(this, arguments);

    // Make the close button a type "button" rather than "submit". This works
    // around an issue in IE9+ where pressing enter would trigger a click of
    // the close button.
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', this.uiDialogTitlebar).attr('type', 'button');
};
```

Comment: there is no need to make this patch on the init dialog.

Comment: @Leandro Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

If the dialog doesn't need to be autoopened, after the dialog has been created and before it's opened:

```
        $("button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").attr("type","button");
```

Also, if you have any button elements in the dialog html, be sure to explicitly include the type="button" attribute in them, or enter in the input control will fire an action associated with the button.

Answer (score 0):

The different between IE9/IE10 and IE11 seems to be that ie9 and 10 activate on keydown, while ie 11 activates the submit button on keyup.

If you are handling keyup to take your own action, it will work on most browsers...except ie 9-10. Another solution is to override keydown, but be careful to still allow certain controls to get the enter key:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.ui-dialog', function (e) {
    var tagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (e.which !== $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) return true;
    if (tagName === 'textarea') return true;
    if (tagName === 'select') return true;
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});
```